# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors: Gradle sync Issues

Tags: java, android

I am newbie on Android Studio. I am getting this error :Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs:

This is my build.gradle (Project)

```
    repositories {

        jcenter()
    google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    google()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my build.gradle (Module app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kartik.barcode"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'//for firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'


}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kartik.barcode"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/un"
        android:label="@string/InventoryManagement"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/myname"

        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,icon,theme,label,name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".login">


        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".register" >

      </activity>
        <activity android:name=".splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        <activity android:name=".records" />
        <activity android:name=".display" />
        <activity android:name=".details">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".chats">

        </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is My errors logs on Merged Manifest

```
app main manifest (this file)

 Other Manifest Files (Included in merge, but did not contribute any elements)
 support-v4:28.0.0 manifest, 
interpolator:1.0.0 manifest, 
support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0 manifest,
 support-media-compat:28.0.0 manifest,
 legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 manifest,
 support:documentfile:28.0.0 manifest,
 support-vector-drawable:28.0.0 manifest, 
support:customview:28.0.0 manifest, 
animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-measurement-sdk:17.0.0 manifest, 
legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 manifest,
 core:runtime:1.1.1 manifest, 
firebase-iid:20.0.0 manifest,
 support:viewpager:28.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-stats:17.0.0 manifest,
 lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0 manifest,
 support:cursoradapter:28.0.0 manifest, 
support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0 manifest, 
customview:1.0.0 manifest, 
support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0 manifest,
 localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0 manifest, 
core-runtime:2.0.0 manifest,
 versionedparcelable:1.0.0 manifest,
 lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0 manifest,
 coordinatorlayout:1.0.0 manifest, 
lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1 manifest, 
zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2 manifest,
 support-core-utils:28.0.0 manifest,
 firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0 manifest, 
lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1 manifest, 
drawerlayout:1.0.0 manifest,
 firebase-appindexing:19.0.0 manifest, 
firebase-auth-interop:18.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-measurement-sdk-api:17.0.0 manifest,
 appcompat-v7:28.0.0 manifest, 
play-services-measurement-base:17.0.0 manifest,
 firebase-auth:19.0.0 manifest, 
firebase-database:19.1.0 manifest, 
loader:1.0.0 manifest,
 support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0 manifest, 
support:loader:28.0.0 manifest,
 asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0 manifest,
 firebase-common:19.1.0 manifest,
 play-services-ads:18.2.0 manifest,
 firebase-database-collection:17.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-base:17.1.0 manifest, 
lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0 manifest, 
viewpager:1.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-ads-base:18.2.0 manifest, 
play-services-gass:18.2.0 manifest,
 support-compat:28.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-auth:17.0.0 manifest,
 browser:1.0.0 manifest, 
cursoradapter:1.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-basement:17.0.0 manifest, 
play-services-auth-base:17.0.0 manifest,
 livedata-core:1.1.1 manifest, 
play-services-ads-lite:18.2.0 manifest, 
slidingpanelayout:1.0.0 manifest, 
support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0 manifest,
 support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0 manifest,
 support:drawerlayout:28.0.0 manifest, 
core:1.0.0 manifest, 
play-services-measurement:17.0.0 manifest,
 lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0 manifest, 
support-core-ui:28.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0 manifest,
 support-fragment:28.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-tasks:17.0.0 manifest, 
print:1.0.0 manifest, documentfile:1.0.0 manifest,
 support:print:28.0.0 manifest,
 fragment:1.0.0 manifest,
 firebase-messaging:20.0.0 manifest, 
support:customtabs:28.0.0 manifest,
 swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0 manifest, 
support:interpolator:28.0.0 manifest,
 play-services-auth-api-phone:17.0.0 manifest,
 firebase-storage:19.0.1 manifest,
 lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1 manifest,
 support:multidex:1.0.2 manifest,
 firebase-measurement-connector:18.0.0 manifest
```

I have searched for the solution but none works.
HERE IS ERROR BUILD:
[image]
[image]
I do not know where to overcome the errors. Please help. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What is the issue? May be it is related to androdix migration since you are you the latest firebase libraries.

Comment: The issue is when I run, its appear Manifest merger failed with multiple errors.

Comment: I can't Migrate to androidX because it say something usage on my others xml/java files

Comment: share failed build logs with us

Comment: I have edited the post. adding some failed build logs